# purrr::map variant which returns long data.frame

Tags: r, tidyr, purrr

Both `purrr::map_dfr` and `purrr::map_dfc` return a wide `data.frame`.

```
library(tidyverse)

mtcars %>% 
  map_dfr(~is.na(.) %>% mean)

mtcars %>% 
  map_dfc(~is.na(.) %>% mean)
```

both return

```
# A tibble: 1 x 11
    mpg   cyl  disp    hp  drat    wt  qsec    vs    am  gear  carb
  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
1     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0
```

I could make this long with a `tidyr::gather`

```
mtcars %>% 
  map_dfr(~is.na(.) %>% mean) %>% 
  gather
```

which returns

```
# A tibble: 11 x 2
   key   value
   <chr> <dbl>
 1 mpg       0
 2 cyl       0
 3 disp      0
 4 hp        0
 5 drat      0
 6 wt        0
 7 qsec      0
 8 vs        0
 9 am        0
10 gear      0
11 carb      0
```

Is there a `purrr::map*` variant which natively returns a long `data.frame`?

Comment: Calling `map_*` on a data frame means you're mapping over the list of columns, so it makes sense that the resulting data frame would have the same number of columns as the original. Do you instead just want `summarize_all`?

Comment: *tidyverse* functions aim at doing one thing and do it well. Now what "one thing" means is a grey area but the way I see what you want to do is really `summarize_all` + `gather`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is an issue not with the `map_df` functions but with `bind_rows`. All the `_dfr` variant does is call `map` then `bind_rows`. From the documentation `?bind_rows`:

> Note that for historical reasons, lists containing vectors are always
>   treated as data frames. Thus **their vectors are treated as columns**
>   rather than rows, and their inner names are ignored.You can circumvent
>   that behaviour with explicit splicing.

Because your function returns a list of vectors, `bind_rows` will treat each vector as column and return a wide dataframe. Other than your approach with `gather`, you have some other options:

Make your function return a dataframe by using `imap_dfr` to iterate over both the columns and their names. This is a one liner but probably slower.

```r
library(tidyverse)
mtcars %>%
  imap_dfr(~tibble(name = .y, value = is.na(.x) %>% mean))
#> # A tibble: 11 x 2
#>    name  value
#>    <chr> <dbl>
#>  1 mpg       0
#>  2 cyl       0
#>  3 disp      0
#>  4 hp        0
#>  5 drat      0
#>  6 wt        0
#>  7 qsec      0
#>  8 vs        0
#>  9 am        0
#> 10 gear      0
#> 11 carb      0
```

Or, return a named vector instead of a list with `map_dbl`, and then make it a tibble with `enframe`. For this use case, this is the fastest by my benchmarking.

```r
mtcars %>%
  map_dbl(~is.na(.) %>% sum) %>%
  enframe()
#> # A tibble: 11 x 2
#>    name  value
#>    <chr> <dbl>
#>  1 mpg       0
#>  2 cyl       0
#>  3 disp      0
#>  4 hp        0
#>  5 drat      0
#>  6 wt        0
#>  7 qsec      0
#>  8 vs        0
#>  9 am        0
#> 10 gear      0
#> 11 carb      0
```

<sup>Created on 2019-05-23 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Hope that helps!